# Checking $v(x)=\log(-\log|x|^2)$ belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Check if the function $v(x)=\log(-\log|x|^2)$ belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$ if $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<\frac{1}{2}\}$. Are functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ necessarily bounded and continuous?

So we have to show that $\int_\Omega|v(x)|^2dx$ and $\int_\Omega|v'(x)|^2dx$ converges. Now $$\int_\Omega|v(x)|^2dx=\int_\Omega|\log(-\log|x|^2)|^2dx$$

and 
$$\int_\Omega|v'(x)|^2dx=\int_\Omega\Bigg|\frac{1}{x\log x}\Bigg|^2dx$$

I don't know what to do now.
Also for the second part I think the functions for $H^1(\Omega)$ are not necessarily bounded and continuous, but I couldn't construct any example to support that.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what about $v$? Is it bounded or continuous? Also you are working in $n=2$ dimensions so $v'$ doesn't make sense. You have to use $\nabla v$ in the $H^1$ norm. After computing $\nabla v$ switch to polar coordinates in the integral.